Why doesn't QTreeView show newly added node to non-root node in QAbstractItemModel
I created a custom model for QTreeView. The complete minimal code to show the problem is below. If I add a new node to the root node, by clicking "Add Level 1", it shows up. But if I add a new node to the second level by clicking "Add Level 2", it does not show up. That node only shows up if I collapse the parent node and then expand it again. What part of my MyTreeModel is wrong?

I am adding the QT tag, even though my code is PySide6, because the fault is probably in my understanding of the methods of QAbstractItemModel, which is not something specific to Python or to PySide.
Full Code
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Optional

from PySide6.QtCore import QAbstractItemModel, QModelIndex
from PySide6.QtGui import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QTreeView


class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, name: str, parent_node):
        self.name = name
        self.parent_node = parent_node
        self.children: list[TreeNode] = []

    def get_child_by_name(self, name) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
        for child in self.children:
            if child.name == name:
                return child

        return None


class MyTreeModel(QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.root_node = TreeNode("root", None)

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return "Name"

    def rowCount(self, parentIndex):
        if not parentIndex.isValid():
            parentNode = self.root_node
        else:
            parentNode = parentIndex.internalPointer()

        return len(parentNode.children)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            node: TreeNode = index.internalPointer()
            column = index.column()
            match column:
                case 0:
                    return node.name
                case _:
                    return None
        else:
            return None

    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QModelIndex()

        childNode: TreeNode = index.internalPointer()
        parentNode = childNode.parent_node

        if parentNode == self.root_node:
            return QModelIndex()

        row_within_parent = parentNode.children.index(childNode)

        return self.createIndex(row_within_parent, 0, parentNode);

    def index(self, row, column, parentIndex):
        if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parentIndex):
            return QModelIndex()

        if not parentIndex.isValid():
            parentNode = self.root_node
        else:
            parentNode = parentIndex.internalPointer()

        child_node = parentNode.children[row]
        if child_node:
            return self.createIndex(row, column, child_node)
        else:
            return QModelIndex()

    def set_data(self, data: []):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.apply_data(data)
        self.endResetModel()

    def update_data(self, data: []):
        self.apply_data(data, True)

    def apply_data(self, data, notify=False):
        for item in data:
            parent_node = self.root_node;
            for part in item.split("/"):
                existing = parent_node.get_child_by_name(part)
                if existing:
                    parent_node = existing
                else:
                    if notify:
                        parent_index = self.get_index(parent_node)
                        count = len(parent_node.children)
                        self.beginInsertRows(parent_index, count, count)

                    new_node = TreeNode(part, parent_node)
                    parent_node.children.append(new_node)
                    parent_node = new_node

                    if notify:
                        self.endInsertRows()

    def get_index(self, node: TreeNode):
        if not node.parent_node:
            return QModelIndex()

        row = node.parent_node.children.index(node)
        return self.createIndex(row, 0, node.parent_node)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(600, 400)

        button1 = QPushButton("Add Level 1")
        button1.clicked.connect(self.add1)
        button2 = QPushButton("Add Level 2")
        button2.clicked.connect(self.add2)

        row1 = QHBoxLayout()
        row1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        row1.addWidget(button1)
        row1.addWidget(button2)

        self.tree_view = QTreeView()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(row1)
        layout.addWidget(self.tree_view, stretch=1)

        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

    def showEvent(self, event):
        data = ["mammals", "birds", "mammals/dog", "birds/eagle", "mammals/cat"]

        my_model = MyTreeModel()
        my_model.set_data(data)
        self.tree_view.setModel(my_model)
        self.tree_view.expandAll()

    def add1(self):
        data = ["reptiles"]
        m = self.tree_view.model()
        m.update_data(data)

    def add2(self):
        data = ["mammals/rat"]
        m = self.tree_view.model()
        m.update_data(data)


app = QApplication([])
win = MainWindow()
win.show()
app.exec()


The problem is that you're creating QModelIndexes inconsistently with createIndex().
In the index() override, you use the node itself as pointer for createIndex():
    def index(self, row, column, parentIndex):
        ...
        if child_node:
            return self.createIndex(row, column, child_node)

In get_index(), instead, you use the parent:
    def get_index(self, node: TreeNode):
        ...
        return self.createIndex(row, 0, node.parent_node)

This results in an inconsistent behavior, which you can verify by printing the data of the parent_index = self.get_index(parent_node) created within the if notify block:
        if notify:
            parent_index = self.get_index(parent_node)
            print('parent:', parent_index.data()) # < add this line

Which will output:
parent: root

The reason for which it "works" (meaning that the child is properly created) is that the child item is actually added to the correct parent node. The reason for which you don't see it immediately is because you're providing the wrong parent QModelIndex() in beginInsertRow(), so the view doesn't know what to do with it, as the given parent is not the one that should show further child items, therefore it simply ignores it.
The solution is then simple: change the last argument of createIndex() to reflect the same behavior:
    def get_index(self, node: TreeNode):
        ...
        return self.createIndex(row, 0, node)

Note that your parent() implementation is also inconsistent, as you're using the wrong pointer and reference. Let's analyze its code:
    def parent(self, index):
        # correct
        if not index.isValid():
            return QModelIndex()

        childNode = index.internalPointer()
        parentNode = childNode.parent_node

        # again, correct
        if parentNode == self.root_node:
            return QModelIndex()

        # this only finds the row within the parent!
        row_within_parent = parentNode.children.index(childNode)

        # this returns an inconsistent index!
        return self.createIndex(row_within_parent, 0, parentNode)

parent() should return the QModelIndex of a given item, but row_within_parent actually represents the row of the item relative to the parent. createIndex() is then inconsistent, because the above row does not represent the correct pointer used for it. Instead, you should find the row of the parent through the grand parent.
This is also reflected by the inconsistent display of the branch lines (which may not be shown on some OS/QStyles):

As you can see, the "cat" item doesn't show the branch line of the parent (unlike "dog" does), while the top level "birds" item shows a branch that shouldn't exist, since there are no other siblings after it.
Here is the fixed version of the parent() function:
    def parent(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return QModelIndex()

        childNode = index.internalPointer()
        parentNode = childNode.parent_node

        if parentNode == self.root_node:
            return QModelIndex()

        grandParent = parentNode.parent_node

        row_within_parent = grandParent.children.index(parentNode)

        return self.createIndex(row_within_parent, 0, parentNode)

And the branches properly drawn:

Finally, you probably did this for testing purposes, but you should be very careful in what you do within a showEvent(), because it can be triggered in many ways and also completely out of control of the user.
If you want to do something when a widget is shown the first time, then either use a QTimer.singleShot(0, someFunction), or use an internal bool flag.
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        QTimer.singleShot(0, self.initModel)

    def initModel(self):
        data = ["mammals", "birds", "mammals/dog", "birds/eagle", "mammals/cat"]

        my_model = MyTreeModel()
        my_model.set_data(data)
        self.tree_view.setModel(my_model)
        self.tree_view.expandAll()

# alternatively:

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    _firstShow = False
    def showEvent(self, event):
        if not self._firstShow:
            self._firstShow = True
            my_model = MyTreeModel()
            ...

In reality, the above is probably unnecessary, since the view/model is normally unaffected by delayed show events, and they have internal ways to deal with updates and geometry requirements delayed by later displaying.

Thanks. Whilst waiting for replies, I tried more things to find out the problem myself, and after this and that, I gave the full code to A.I. and asked them to find out the problem. I tried Gemini, Copilot, and free ChatGPT (3.5). The first two gave wrong answers like I need to call dataChanged. But surprisingly ChatGPT correctly pointed out that get_index is using the parent node to create the index. The concept of "index" has been very confusing for me. Thanks for pointing out the problem of my parent() function, too.

Didn't know the wrong relationship, because in the venv, PySide6 uses the Fusion style which doesn't show connecting vertical lines. After switching to Breeze, I could see the problem. I don't know why Fusioin, WPF, and other recent frameworks try to hide those vertical lines; they are essential for a tree view, in my opinion. Now I think I understand better what createIndex does.

@DamnVegetables I agree that the branch line is normally preferable, but it can also be confusing when many levels exist (at some point, you just see a lot of vertical lines). The concept of index in Qt models is that a QModelIndex is an absolute reference to an item using 3 elements: its row and column (obviously) and a unique pointer that is some sort of "third coordinate" (similarly to a z value for a 3d graph). What often creates confusion is that the pointer is usually the object to which the QModelIndex refers to, which seems a bit illogical: how can the same pointer (which, in »

@DamnVegetables » theory, should identify a single item in the model) be potentially used with a different row or column? In reality, it can. For example, QTreeWidget uses a single QTreeWidgetItem for the whole row shown (so, the same item is used for all the columns the model displays) and, for simplicity, it uses that item as pointer for createIndex(). Another alternative is to use the parent as pointer, which would make more sense (the row/column are used as "coordinates" relative to the parent), but may not be ideal in all cases. Basically, you could use anything as the index »

@DamnVegetables » pointer (including numbers or strings); the point is that it must always be consistent: the combination of row, column and pointer should always reflect a specific item. What is actually used as pointer is a matter or requirements; using the parent is theoretically appropriate and logically simpler, but makes access to the item itself more complex: internalPointer() returns the parent, so you always need to do further calls in order to get the actual item data based on its row and column; that may not be ideal for large models, because some functions such as data(), »

@DamnVegetables » index() or flags() are called very frequently (a mouse movement alone could cause dozens if not hundreds of requests), and they should always return as soon as possible; obviously, if a function always needs to get the child of a "parent pointer", the delay may become unbearable, as the updates on the view wouldn't happen until the whole painting is completed, resulting in a less responsive UI or temporary freeze, especially in case of recursive calls (which are common in tree models).

QTreeView (and its Simple\Editable Tree Model examples) is\are the poorest implementations I've seen for developers to work from. What you should be doing is implementing a proper MVC (Model View Controller) pattern. Build your own data structure (the Model class); Do all the updating of the Model using your own methods (that's in a Controller class), and then use the Controller to update a View class (that latter then drives the GUI, in this instance a QTreeView object). For user interaction, you have pointers contained inside each element of the QTreeView (i.e. use the InternalPointer field of each row) that point into the tree structure (the model). There should be no need for QModelIndexes at all in the Model - the Controller handles all the mappings between Model and View. All queries you make of the Model you do via your Controller class, not via the QTreeView. If you implement MVC correctly you can very easily change the View independently, for example to be an old style ASCII terminal tree or whatever. This also isolates your database from any bugs\issues in the QT subsystem.
:o)
